# How could I pull out multiple URLs from an Excel Cell?

Tags: excel, url, extract

In excel 2007 how could I go about extracting just the URLs from a cell containing the following?

"ITEMIMAGEURL1=http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/73001099/images/ap1240__a.jpg,ITEMIMAGEURL2=http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/73001099/images/ap1240__b.jpg"

Some cells have up to 12 different URLs.

Ideally I could extract URL 1 & place it in its own column, then URL 2 and place it in its own column.

Comment: I used brucewaynes suggestion below and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without getting in to VBA, here's something that would work.

Have your cell(s) selected, and go to the Data tab, "Text to Columns". Choose "Delimited", and for the delimiter, in the "Other" blank, put `=`.  Click "Finish" and Excel will separate the URLs in the same row.

Then, under those, you can enter this formula (assuming your data is in Row 1):
`=IF(LEFT(B1,4)<>"Item",IFERROR(LEFT(B1,SEARCH(",",B1)-1),B1),"")` and drag over.

Your A1 will just have "ITEMIMAGEURL1", but in B1, it'll be blank.  B2 will just be the URL of the first URL, C2 will be second URL, etc.

[Here's a .gif](http://i.imgur.com/v9LpJ7g.gifv) to show you what I did.

Comment: Went this route and it worked perfectly :) since I'm pretty new to excel this solution was definitely the most intuitive.  thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! @Jeeped's answer is a good one as well.  As you get more comfortable, take some time to see if you can figure out what it's doing - it's pretty clever.

Answer (score 2):

With the first multi-URL in A2 put this formula into B2,

```
=MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&$A2, ",ITEMIMAGEURL", REPT(" ", 999)), COLUMN(A:A)*999, 999)), 3+(COLUMN(A:A)>9), 999)
```

Fill right an additional 11 columns. Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Comment: I think it might need another [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) as a final wrapper to get rid of extraneous `=` if the `ITEMIMAGEURL` goes into double digits; e.g. ITEMIMAGEURL10=....

Comment: Slight modification to compensate for ITEMIMAGEURL10-12 added to above formula.

Answer (score 0):

With the first multi-URL in A1, put this formula in B1

```
=MID($A1,FIND("IMAGEURL"&COLUMN()-1,$A1)+10,IF(ISERR(FIND("IMAGEURL"&COLUMN(),$A1)),LEN($A1),FIND(",",$A1,FIND("IMAGEURL"&COLUMN()-1,$A1))-10-FIND("IMAGEURL"&COLUMN()-1,$A1)))
```

Fill right an additional 11 columns. Fill down as necessary.